# Как спрятать ссылку в слово в python 3 телеграм бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем привет!

Сразу хочу сказать, что я новичек в пайтон и столкнулся на первый взгляд с **элементарной** вещью.

К сути:

Я делаю телеграм бота с билиотекой ***telebot*** мне нужно реализовать, чтобы бот отправлял целый оформленный пост.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это я написал довольно просто как:

```
def post(message):
if message.text == "Начать":
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_docs= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='post', url='https://tgraph.io/')
    markup.add(btn_docs)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Типовые учебные планы предшкольной программы:", reply_markup = markup)
```

Теперь у меня вопрос как мне скрыть ссылку под словом "На телефоне" и "На компьютере" один будет вести на telegra.ph другой на зеркало tgraph.io.

**Как мне это реализовать в коде?**

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [Markdown](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style) или [HTML](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style) в `parse_mode`:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ссылка](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) на документацию про форматирование (в России потребует прокси/vpn для открытия).

Метод `sendMessage` на вход одним из параметров принимает строку `parse_mode`, к которой будет применено форматирование с помощью:

MarkdownV2 style

```
[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
```

или HTML style

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
```